# resolveLocalFileSystemURL on iOS using different App UUID each time

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, filesystems, uuid

I am using Cordova fileSystem to download some mp3 Audio files thru my App. I am using cordova.file.cacheDirectory and creating a subfolder within that to store the downloaded files. However, the problem is that each time I make some changes and run the App on iPad I get a different path.

The usual pattern is

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/13E9EA83-94A2-4950-811E-E491AC176‌​A78/Library/Caches/MyFolder/MyFiles.mp3
```

However the long number (App UUID) is not consistent. It changes each time I run the App on iPad through Xcode. Because of this I am unable to access, play, delete any files downloaded during the previous session because I am saving the file names with absolute path in a separate file for quick access in the future.

Answer (score 1):

After some R&D I have realized that even though UUID changes each time, it actually refers to the same location. Hence the solution is not to save absolute path and instead, save only the Path beyond "/MyFolder/" in the above example. Each time when the App is run, the Base Path, which is actually file.cordova.cacheDirectory, should be appended to each entry to obtain the absolute Path to the file.

Comment: I don't care that this post is 2 years old, this has just ended by 2 day battle with my app. Kids will sing songs about you in the streets, and how important you were to the development of mankind.